java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only a single call to `runTest` can be performed during one test
I'm trying to use DocLocScreenshotTestCase from the kaspresso framework to create a test that prepares screenshots in different locales, for DI used Hilt
@HiltAndroidTest
class StartOnboardingScreenshots: DocLocScreenshotTestCase(locales = "ru, en, de, es") {
    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)
    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    fun takeScreenshots() = run {
        step("Take initial state screenshots") {
            ComposeScreen.onComposeScreen<KFirstScreen>(composeTestRule) {
                assertIsDisplayed()
                captureScreenshot("Initial state")
            }
        }
    }
}

but after running the test in the first locale in the second locale, it crashes,

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only a single call to `runTest` can be performed during one test.
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestScopeImpl.enter(TestScope.kt:222)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:309)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source:1)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(TestBuilders.kt:305)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(Unknown Source:1)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.withTestCoroutines(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:370)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.access$withTestCoroutines(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:230)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$runTest$1$1$1.invoke(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:324)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.EspressoLink.withStrategy(EspressoLink.android.kt:66)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$runTest$1$1.invoke(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:323)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.IdlingResourceRegistry.withRegistry(IdlingResourceRegistry.jvm.kt:157)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$runTest$1.invoke(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:322)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.ComposeRootRegistry.withRegistry(ComposeRootRegistry.android.kt:146)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.runTest(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:321)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule$apply$1.evaluate(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:271)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.MarkThatRulesRanRule$1.evaluate(MarkThatRulesRanRule.java:108)
at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:136)
at com.kaspersky.kaspresso.docloc.rule.ToggleNightModeRule$apply$1.evaluate(ToggleNightModeRule.kt:33)
at com.kaspersky.kaspresso.docloc.rule.LocaleRule.changeLanguageInApp(LocaleRule.kt:47)
at com.kaspersky.kaspresso.docloc.rule.LocaleRule.access$changeLanguageInApp(LocaleRule.kt:14)
at com.kaspersky.kaspresso.docloc.rule.LocaleRule$apply$1.evaluate(LocaleRule.kt:34)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:67)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:446)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2361)

as I understand it, due to the rule for hilt.
Does anyone understand how this can be fixed?
The test will complete successfully
